# can we add graduation to an oval form using CSS?

Tags: css

i want to add graduation mark to an oval shape using css, to get the level, let say at 25 % , 50% and 75 %, just a A score mark ('-')

the code i'm using to draw the form is

```
.circle {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsouhaieb/tLq971xj/)

what i want to get is something like this:

[image: Imgur]

and thanks in advance for everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a gradient for the main coloration and also for the mark:

```css
.circle {
    background:
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) 0 25%/50px 5px,  /*top */
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) 0 50%/100px 5px, /*middle */
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) 0 75%/50px 5px,  /*bottom*/
      /*main color*/
      linear-gradient(red,red) bottom/100% 75%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<span class="circle"></span>
```

And with CSS variable you can make it easy to adjust:

```css
.circle {
    background:
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) 0 25%/50px 5px,
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) 0 50%/100px 5px,
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) 0 75%/50px 5px,
      /*main color*/
      linear-gradient(red,red) bottom/100% var(--p,100%);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle" style="--p:60%"></span>
<span class="circle" style="--p:50%"></span>
<span class="circle" style="--p:30%"></span>
```

Comment: is there another way, because i want to integrate it in react native ?

Comment: @Souhaieb react don't allow gradient?

Comment: i find out after posting the question, that is why i'm asking if there is another way, thanks anyway